# Css and span class height inside a paragraph

Tags: css

How can I make the background of `.post_headline_signup` the same height as the background of the paragraph inside the div.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="post_headline">
    <p>Hello world<span class="post_headline_signup"><a href="site">text inside span</a></span></p> 
</div>
```

This is my css:

```
.post_headline {
background:url(images/signup_bg.jpg) repeat-x;
border-left:1px solid #555;
border-right:1px solid #555;
padding-left:1em;
height:2em;
line-height:2em
}
.post_headline p {
text-transform:uppercase
}
.post_headline a { 
font-weight:bold;
background:url(images/signup.jpg) repeat-x #900;
border-left:1px solid #000;
border-right:1px solid #000;
padding:1.2em; - **THE PROBLEM IS HERE - ONLY PADDING WORKS, LINE HEIGHT OR DIV HEIGHT DOESN'T**
margin-left:1em
} 
.post_headline a:hover { 
color:#FFF; 
text-decoration:underline 
}
```

Ty!

Comment: `.post_headline_signup` does not have a background in your CSS… Try setting the anchor to `display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background images cannot (in css2) stretch to fit their container. if you need it to stretch then you will have to have it as an <img/> (which is not great either (presentation vs content) however that is a limitation of css2. Css3 may offer background stretching but I dont think I have seen it)